# Burninate [open]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

The [open](/questions/tagged/open) tag is hopelessly vague; based on the tagged questions I currently see, it can refer to:

- Accessing files in any number of languages. In some languages, there are better terms for this (e.g, [stdio](/questions/tagged/stdio)). In others, it's a basic task that shouldn't need its own tag.
- Opening windows, applications, and documents, or picking files to open, in many different unrelated environments. There's nothing in common to all these questions, as the answer will depend entirely on the environment.
- Network ports being "open".
- Various compound tags, like [open](/questions/tagged/open) [xml](/questions/tagged/xml), [open](/questions/tagged/open) [layers](/questions/tagged/layers), [open](/questions/tagged/open) [graph](/questions/tagged/graph).

There are currently 825 questions tagged as [open](/questions/tagged/open). Can we get some Trogdor up in here?

Comment: For most questions that I saw (quick glance), I/O seems to be a more appropriate tag.  Silverlight-specific functions *could* have their own tag.  As for this tag itself - may the flames take it.

Comment: The effort in March seems to have been focussed on a combination of the tags [open] and [source]. I don't think all the [open] tags you see now are new since that date.

Comment: @Bart: Aha, right you are. Point stands, though!

Comment: Yeah, we're up to almost 1000 now, with about 100 being mis-tagged with `open` and `graph` instead of `opengraph`

Comment: Trogdor can't help until cleanup is done. If there are a lot of mistaggings, we need to fix all those first, not just burn off the tag.

Comment: @animuson can we use [tag:file-io] for those related to files?